Does 'with' statements are not allowed in strict mode.ts(1101) error been resolved?
I have an assignment to create an CRUD with NodeJS + Typescript + ES6 module system.
I was given json file with database, I need to work with.
At first I tried imported json file like this:
index.html:
<script type="module" src="script.js"></script>

script.js
import data from "./data.json" assert { type: "json" };

Typescript didn't show any error, but JS said that assert is depricated. So I switched to with:
script.js
import data from "./data.json" with { type: "json" };

And this is when I received and error message: 'with' statements are not allowed in strict mode.ts(1101).
I tried to find anything on internet, but everything it showed either didn't work or suggested to turn off strict mode. But one of the requirements is to use strict mode. So the option of turning it off will not work for me.
So my question is: is there any way to import json file in NodeJs ES6 module system with Typescript's strict mode?

I don't understand the need for the { type: "json" } in the first place, what's wrong with just import data from "./data.json"?

That was recommended to do for typescript so it will understand that he is working with json file and not an imported string.
